# How to trace which file adds js script

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, magento-1.9.3.6

I'm working on a `1.9.3.6` project in which the header has 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mage1936.local/skin/frontend/mytheme/default/"></script>`
that causes a `403` console error

I've tried to find all modules and layout files adding js to `head` and missing the file name. but looks like not that case and not the way I should trace this issue.

How should I trace a case like that?

Answer (score 0):

Check here for the manually inserted script:

> /app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/template/page/html/head.phtml

If the file doesn't exist, check the in the base file:

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml

You can also do a text search for `skin/frontend/mytheme/default/` in your `/app/design/frontend/` folder to check all .phtml files.

And you can search for `<action method="addItem"><type>js</type>` in all layout XML files. JS tags can be added by this method as well.